# jquery function working well in chrome, but throws error in firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, search

please help me out with this error that i get in my Firefox. the function is working well in chrome, i just wish it could work in the same way in Firefox too. this is the script that seems to have the problem.

```
function OpenmrsSearch(div, showIncludeVoided, searchHandler, selectionHandler, fieldsAndHeaders, opts) {
var el;
if(typeof div == 'string') {
    el = jQuery("#" + div);
}

if(!opts) {
    opts = {};
}

if(!opts.showIncludeVoided) 
    opts.showIncludeVoided = showIncludeVoided;
if(!opts.selectionHandler) 
    opts.selectionHandler = selectionHandler;
if(!opts.searchHandler)
    opts.searchHandler = searchHandler;
if(!opts.fieldsAndHeaders)
    opts.fieldsAndHeaders = fieldsAndHeaders;

jQuery(el).openmrsSearch(opts);
}
```

firebug throws the following error.

> > TypeError: jQuery(...).openmrsSearch is not a function

```
jQuery(el).openmrsSearch(opts);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TypeError: jQuery(...)
```

This indicates, there's a conflict in your jQuery or jQuery library not included, or may be there's no such function. 
Try including jQuery library before your script, 
still occurs try including ,

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

before your script! Hope it helps.

Comment: let me try that and come back with a reply.. thanks for the prompt reply

Comment: I should have mentioned earlier that am working on an opensource project. thus the javascript that throws the exception cannot be edited.. al i can do is maybe create my own script and include it in my jsp.. i tried the above but it did not work for me..i should say it works well in chrome

Comment: dose it throw an error or functionality is not achievable. Some errors can be caused by Firefox. Chrome is just for user experience. Firefox kind a developer console!

Comment: the error thrown is TypeError: jQuery(...).openmrsSearch is not a function
 jQuery(el).openmrsSearch(opts);

Comment: Firebug installed right. if the red arrow on the eroor points to jQuery, it normally type error corresponds jquery no conflict. try before youre script : including jquery lib, then jQuery.noConflict();